# condicion where sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta que me trae el siguiente resultado:

```
SISTEMA_OPE SUC_OPE CVE_SISTEMA CVA_SUC_ORI SUCURSAL_ORI    DESTINO SUCURSAL_DESTINO    ESTATUS
0               18      0           2           X           18          X       RECIBIDO
0               18      0           2           Y           18          Y       RECIBIDO
0               1       0           3           Z           107         Z       RECOLECCION
0               1       1           1           T           439         T       RECIBIDO
```

Quiero traer como resultado si `(CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE)<>CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)` pero si ESTATUS ES DIFERENTE A "RECIBIDO", PERO TENGO UN CASO EN LOS ULTIMAS FILAS QUE PONGO NO TIENE NADA DE RELACION ESTO `(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE)<>CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)` PERO QUIERO QUE LO MUESTRE, PERO  LO QUE NO ES COMO ESTATUS RECIBIDO, YO TENGO LA CONDICION ASI:

```
WHERE SUC_OPE='001' AND SISTEMA_OPE='0' AND ((CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) 
<>CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)) OR 
(CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE)=CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO) AND 
ESTATUS<>'RECIBIDO'))
```

la consulta me trae:

```
0               1       1           1           T           439         T       RECIBIDO
```

y no quiero que lo traiga me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si das un poco de formato a tu condición, enseguida te das cuenta de lo que hace

```
WHERE SUC_OPE='001' 
AND SISTEMA_OPE='0' 
AND (
      (
        CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) <> CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)
      ) OR 
      (
        CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE)=CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO) AND 
        ESTATUS <> 'RECIBIDO'
      )
    )
```

Como puedes ver lo que estas haciendo es decir le exactamente :

Traeme los registros donde :

SUC_OPE='001'
SISTEMA_OPE='0'
Y (
     donde CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) es diferente a  CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)
     O
     donde CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) es igual a CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO) y el 
     estado es diferente a RECIBIDO
  )

Por lo tanto es normal que te traiga este registro ya que se cumple la condicion:
donde CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) es diferente a  CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO)

Espero que esto te ayude.
Saludos.

Comment: Y cómo podría acomodarlo para que me de el resultado esperado ?

Comment: Creo que con las indicaciones que te di deberias poder constuirlo, pero a ver si te doy la solución ya hecha. Entiendo que lo que quieres es traer resultados que tengan (CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) diferente a CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO) y su ESTATUS es diferente a "RECIBIDO" si es asi aqui esta tu condición :  WHERE SUC_OPE='001' 
AND SISTEMA_OPE='0' 
AND (
      CONCAT(SISTEMA_OPE,SUC_OPE) <> CONCAT(CVE_SISTEMA,DESTINO) AND
   ESTATUS <> 'RECIBIDO'
    )

Comment: me sirvio solo adapte un poco a mi consulta muchas gracias!!!